# Error al cargar las fuentes en Expo

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, fuentes

Quiero cargar una fuente en mi app desarrollada en React-Native con Expo.
La fuente se encuentra descargada en la carpeta que aparece en el código, pero me aparece el siguiente error:

TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Quiero que la fuente se cargue dentro de mi archivo de estilos global, ya que quiero aplicar la familia en el estilo botonTexto de abajo:

```
import {StyleSheet, useFonts} from 'react-native';

  import colors from '../../config/colors';

  const [loaded] = useFonts({
    aqua: require('../../assets/Fuentes/aqua.ttf')
  });

  export const estiloGlobal = StyleSheet.create({
cajas: {
  marginVertical: 10,
  paddingStart: 20,
  borderRadius: 25,
  width: 300,
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: colors.rosa,
},
boton: {
  marginVertical: 10,
  paddingStart: 20,
  borderRadius: 25,
  justifyContent: "center",
  width: 300,
  height: 50,
  backgroundColor: colors.colorPrimaryDark,
},
botonTexto: {
  color: colors.white,
  fontFamily: 'aqua',
  fontSize: '35'
}
```

});

También he probado a tratar de cargar la fuente desde la función principal de mi código, pero me da el mismo error.
Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useFont` es un [custom hook](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) (también conocido como "hook personalizado"), por esta razón **no** puedes usarlo fuera de un componente funcional, es una de las [reglas de hooks](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions).

Para que el font esté disponible en toda tu aplicación, primero debes cargarlo en el componente principal (tipicamente `App.js`) usando el custom hook `useFont`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import { globalStyles } from './globalStyles'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font';

const App = () => {
  
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Star Jedi': require('./assets/fonts/Starjedi.ttf'),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={globalStyles.container}>
        <Text style={globalStyles.text}>
          star wars
        </Text>
        <Text>El resto de tu aplicación va aquí</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export default App
```

Tus archivo de estilos se veria algo así:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const globalStyles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1, 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
    alignItems: 'center' 
  },
  text: {
    fontFamily: 'Star Jedi', 
    fontSize: 40
  }
});
```

Aclaración: Yo le di el nombre `globalStyles` en vez de `estiloGlobal`

Ejemplo funcional [aquí](https://snack.expo.io/@jmmarco/custom-font).

Answer (score 0):

para importar fuentes a nuestro proyecto de react native expo hay que usar la libreria expo-font que ya viene instalada ,luego en la vista donde la queremos usar ponemos un `componentDidMount` y dentro de este la ruta de nuestra fuente.

quedaria algo asi:

```
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

componentDidMount(){
Font.loadAsync({
   
  aqua: require('../../assets/Fuentes/aqua.ttf'),
 
 });
}


botonTexto: {
fontFamily: 'aqua',
fontSize: '35'
}
```

Comment: Entiendo que esto podría funcionar si tuviera un componente, que no es mi caso, ya que quiero cargarlo desde el archivo de estilos.